# Select forms to go through file heirarchy

Tags: javascript, php, html, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have the following select form that goes through a folder and sets all the .csv files to be select items for a dropdown menu.

```
<select name="a_select" id="a_select">
    <?php
    $files = glob("output/*.csv");
    foreach ($files as $file){
        $filename = basename($file, '.csv');
        echo "<option value='$filename'>$filename</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
```

This form goes through the "output" folder.  Now, suppose I have multiple "output" folders that are subdirectories of other folders, "fold1", "fold2", and "fold3".  I'd like to have a dynamically-generated select menu to get the names of these three directories, BUT also have the above code modified so that it only shows the applicable dropdowns for the .csv files in the directory that is dictated by this new dropdown menu.

Here's my take on it so far: I know that I can make a select menu that has dropdown values of the folders located in a directory.  I can also modify the above code to be as follows:

```
<select name="a" id="a">
    <?php
    $files = glob($otherFolderName + "output/*.csv");
    foreach ($files as $file){
        $filename = basename($file, '.csv');
        echo "<option value='$filename'>$filename</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
```

where `$otherFolderName` is the selected value of the dropdown that has folders as choices.  However, the part that I'm not sure how to do is the following pseudocode:

```
$otherFolderName = get_selected_value(a_select)
```

It would also be nice if all select menus could auto-update (i.e. no "submit" button).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!